# Primefaces datatable header searchbox breaks table layout

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a realy strange behavior if i place components inside a datatable header.

Code for the Table

```
<p:dataTable id="groupTable" var="group" value="#{profile.user.groups}"
                             widgetVar="groupTable" rows="10" paginator="true"
                             paginatorPosition="bottom"
                             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,20,40,80"
                             emptyMessage="Keine Einträge mit den gewünschten Kriterien gefunden"
                             filteredValue="#{groupView.filteredGroups}" sortMode="multiple"
                             resizableColumns="true" liveResize="true">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Zugeordnete Gruppen" />
        <p:outputPanel style="float:left;">
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('groupTable').filter()" style="width:150px;" placeholder="Suche"/>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </f:facet>

    <p:column headerText="Gruppenname" filterBy="#{group.name}"
                              sortBy="#{group.name}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                              filterStyle="display:none" style="width:150px">
        <h:outputText value="#{group.name}"/>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Beschreibung" filterBy="#{group.beschreibung}"
                              sortBy="#{group.beschreibung}" filterMatchMode="contains"
                              filterStyle="display:none">
         <h:outputText value="#{group.beschreibung}"/>
     </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

you can find the generated HTML here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2co3oz5c/)

On the Page itself it looks like this:
[image: Page]

So what is the problem with the code? why does the serach box destroy the table layout?

Comment: Define strange behaviour…

Comment: I mean the Searchbox which is destroying the table layout. As you can see in the image

Comment: I changed the topic to a more precise topicname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found it. Maybe it will help someday another facing the same Problem.

The Searchbox is to big in line with the Text. If i change the `inputtext` size and set the `outputpanel` inline it looks like it was intended.

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Zugeordnete Gruppen" />
    <p:outputPanel style="display:inline">
        <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('groupTable').filter()" style="width:150px;height:10px;float:left" placeholder="Suche"/>
    </p:outputPanel>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: Asking questions in answers is in general a bad idea

Comment: Asking questions in answers is seriously forbidden. :)